# Lost password for a user on a Linux Server: How reset it?

Tags: password, passwd

On a Server an user 16040 has lost his password. I have password for root but don't have password for user 16040. How can I reset his password?

With `passwd 16040`, unix ask me current password that I don't have. Is there a command for reset a user's password without current password?

```
passwd 16040
Changing password for 16040.
Current password for 16040@friesbie.com:
```

Answer (score 24):

If you run `passwd 16040` as root, you will not be asked for the current password.

After changing the password, you should consider issuing `chage -d 0 16040`. This sets the password's last change date far in the past; assuming passwords are set to expire on your system, this will force the user to change their password after logging in. This gives them a chance to choose a password only known to them.

Answer (score 3):

You should issue `passwd 16040` as root (`sudo passwd 16040` if your user is in the sudoers file) to change his/her password. It won't ask you for the current one.

Or, if you have physical access to the box, you can append `init=/bin/bash` as kernel parameter to get root access and then issue `passwd 16040`.

Comment: Having a prompt in inline commands is rather puzzling and can easily be misinterpreted as being part of the command.  Please only use prompts in block quotes.  Additionally, `# >` is rather uncommon and here `>` simply invites to be misinterpreted as part of the command — common practice is using a simple `#` for `root`-shells and `$` for non-root ones.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my answer for sake of clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot log directly as a root you can try

- `sudo /usr/bin/passwd 16040`.
- `sudo -i` and after `/usr/bin/passwd 16040`

I'm assuming that `passwd` is in /usr/bin (you can verify with the command `which passwd`)

Comment: `sudo bash` for starting a `root` shell is (although common) really, really bad `sudo` practice.  It's `sudo -s` or `sudo -i` (non-login or login-shell, resp.).  This even honors your default shell set in `/etc/passwd` without having to care about it yourself.  Additionally, `bash` without a complete path is a bad idea on its own, since this would be one of the first fake-binaries a malicious user would put somewhere into `$PATH`.

Comment: I agree about the full path specification, and the use of `sudo -i`, and so I modified the answer... but if you speak about security and the possibility of a troian hidden in the `$PATH` maybe it's better to avoid to use `sudo -s` since you add at least the `$USER/bin` directory and all the alias you can imagine... :-)

Comment: Good point, indeed, but depends on `sudo` configuration: the default configuration shipped with `sudo` doesn't keep the `$HOME` variable set, thus you'd end up having your own rc-files sourced, not the `$SUDO_USER`'s ones.